# Return XML builder response to variable in controller in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have an object `@product` and a XML builder in my views directory called `download.xml.builder`

I am using this code to generate a XML file:

```
format.xml { send_data(render_to_string(:template=>"download" ), :type=>"text/xml",:filename => "download.xml") }
```

But what I need now is that my controller does not generate a file but simply stores the XML into a variable `@download` (I will use this to send it to a SOAP API)

Comment: Do you using Rails API version?

Comment: No, I am using the regular RoR

Answer (score 0):

I checked my old project (Rails 3) with correct xml builder, and can suggest you to try similar solution:

some_controller.rb

```
def getxml
  respond_to :xml
end
```

views/some/getxml.xml.builder

```
xml.instruct!
xml.some_tag {
  xml.simple_string "some string"

  xml.simple_node {
    xml.foo "..."
    xml.bar "..."
  }
}
```

I'm not sure, about using it for SOAP API, but hope that will point the way.